# How can I make my Python code run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to filter or delete values and my code take long time. And also, these are very small files because I will run same process on bigger files. I have Windows pro, Xeon, 64 RAM, SDD but only use 4%. So how I can improve? Maybe with numpy, pandas or async, multiprocessing and multithreading?

```
df = pd.read_csv('rent3_dupli_mayor_0.csv', sep = ',', dtype='unicode', low_memory=False)
dfr_3 = pd.read_csv('renta3_3_1.csv', sep = ',', dtype='unicode', low_memory=False)
dfr_3.describe(include='all')
df.describe(include='all')
```

[image: describe dataframes]

```
list_3_1=pd.unique(df['v1']).tolist()
for ddel1 in list_3_1:
    dfr_3 = dfr_3[dfr_3.v1 != ddel1]
```

Maybe a for loop is wrong way. Looping taking too much time.
How I can improve my code? I am trying to delete all numbers of my list (unique values: 201429) that I can find in my dataframe. If you can see my dataframe has 22704716 (line of values).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
dfr_3 = dfr_3[~dfr_3.v1.isin(list_3_1)]
```